# force download file with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, download, laravel-5, laravel-response

So i'm using Laravel 5 and I tried to force download a selected file but nothing happens.

```
public function downloadUserFile(){
        $result = $_POST['filename'];
        $entry = File::where('filename', $result)->firstOrFail();
        $file = Storage::disk()->get($entry->filePath);
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => $entry->mimetype);
        return response()->download(storage_path($entry->filePath), $result, $headers);
}
```

and the response headers seem to be ok

```
Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: public
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="SIGNAL - Nadezdata.mp3"
Content-Length: 4205059
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in paths.

By default in `config/filesystems.php` local path is defined this way: `storage_path('app')` and you pass into download the following path: `storage_path($entry->filePath)` (no `app` included here).

What you should do is changing:

```
return response()->download(storage_path($entry->filePath), $result, $headers);
```

into:

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/'.$entry->filePath), $result, $headers);
```

Comment: I've already changed it. But i haven't passed nothing to the view.Could this be the problem?

Comment: What view do you mean? You don't use here any view, after click you simple force browser to download file and that's it

Comment: But nothing happens. There is no force download